# Using xs:alternative with extended types that may or may not have elements

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I would like to use XSD 1.1 and create a schema that allows alternatives based on an attribute value. I have found out how to do that via some other posts. However, I have a use-case that I can't seem to find anywhere nor an answer for.

I would like to have 1 or more elements with the name PARAM. Each of these elements has a 'key' attribute and based on the value of this attribute the PARAM element *might* have child elements or might not (might just have other attributes).

However, I'm getting an error that implies this might not be possible but I can't find any documentation or anything to confirm.

Here is my XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="CONFIG">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <!-- any number of PARAM elements, setting alternative types based on the key attribute value -->
                <xs:element name="PARAM" type="baseParamType" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:alternative test="@key='printers'" type="printerParamType"/>
                    <xs:alternative test="@key!='printers'" type="nonPrinterParamType"/>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <!--
        Type Declarations
    -->

    <!-- base PARAM type -->
    <xs:complexType name="baseParamType">
        <xs:attribute name="key" use="required" type="paramKeyTypes"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <!-- PARAM for printers -->
    <xs:complexType name="printerParamType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <!-- extend the base PARAM type -->
            <xs:extension base="baseParamType">
                <!-- the printer PARAM can have a child FORMAT element -->
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="FORMAT" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:attribute name="name" use="required" type="printerFormatType"/>
                            <xs:attribute name="printer" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <!-- PARAM for anything but printers -->
    <xs:complexType name="nonPrinterParamType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="baseParamType">
                <xs:attribute name="value" use="required" />
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <!-- valid values for the key attribute of PARAM elements -->
    <xs:simpleType name="paramKeyTypes">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="printers"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="locale"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="debug_mode"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="num_threads"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="serial_printer"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="parallel_printer"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="NCRTwoLine"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="requires_line_AB"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="printer_type"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="epson_mode"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="sequence_file"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="disable_cashdrawer"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="tax_label"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="dynamic_gateway_config"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="gateway_settings"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="use_static_gateway_config"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <!-- valid values for printer names -->
    <xs:simpleType name="printerFormatType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="default" />
            <xs:enumeration value="receipt" />
            <xs:enumeration value="ticket" />
            <xs:enumeration value="season_pass" />
            <xs:enumeration value="forms" />
            <xs:enumeration value="demographics" />
            <xs:enumeration value="group" />
            <xs:enumeration value="report" />
            <xs:enumeration value="boca" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

And here is the file being validated:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CONFIG xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="config.xsd">
    <PARAM key="printers">
        <FORMAT name="default" printer="Microsoft XPS Document Writer" />
        <FORMAT name="receipt" printer="Microsoft XPS Document Writer" />
        <FORMAT name="group" printer="Microsoft XPS Document Writer" />
        <FORMAT name="ticket" printer="Microsoft XPS Document Writer" />
        <FORMAT name="season_pass" printer="Microsoft XPS Document Writer" />
    </PARAM>

    <PARAM key="dynamic_gateway_config" value="http://test-shop.accesso.com/pos/getEnvironment.php" island="accesso90"/>
</CONFIG>
```

The error I'm getting:

```
[Error] config.xsd:9:85: s4s-elt-must-match.1: The content of 'PARAM' must match (annotation?, (simpleType | complexType)?, (unique | key | keyref)*)). A problem was found starting at: alternative.
[Error] config.cfg:10:13: cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'PARAM' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty.
[Error] config.cfg:12:121: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'value' is not allowed to appear in element 'PARAM'.
[Error] config.cfg:12:121: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'island' is not allowed to appear in element 'PARAM'.
[Error] config.cfg:10:13: cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'PARAM' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty.
[Error] config.cfg:12:121: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'value' is not allowed to appear in element 'PARAM'.
[Error] config.cfg:12:121: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'island' is not allowed to appear in element 'PARAM'.
```

I'm mostly concerned with the first error stating that PARAM must have no character or element information because the type's content is empty. I *think* it is saying that because my 'baseParamType' type has no elements defined that the PARAM with a key value of 'printers' can't have any child elements, but it's a tad cryptic.

What I would like to have is to be able to have both of the following in the same XML

```
<PARAM key="printers">
    <FORMAT name="someName" printer="Some printer name" />
</PARAM>

<PARAM key="anythingButPrinters" value="some value" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error:

```
The content of 'PARAM' must match (annotation?, (simpleType | complexType)?,
 (unique | key | keyref)*)). A problem was found starting at: alternative.
```

is a pretty good indication that it's complaining about the schema rather than the instance document, though I always find it odd that Xerces talks about the "content of 'PARAM'" rather than the "content of xs:element".

It all comes up as valid in Saxon-EE 9.9, so it's either a bug in Xerces or more likely you're somehow running it in a way where XSD 1.1 processing isn't enabled.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I will look further into Xerces. I had a bit of trouble at first with getting it set up to rest at all. Hopefully it's as simple as that!